# Name of the downloaded file in <af:fileDownloadActionListener>, calculated directly when clicking <af:commandImageLink>

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am trying to improve an old application that uses Oracle ADF 12c.
I need to compute the file name before it will be downloaded.

Currently the download of the file is written like this.

```
<af:table value="#{DocListManagedBean.list}" var="row" 
    disableColumnReordering="true" varStatus="vs" id="t1" 
    columnStretching="column:c2" emptyText="#{PageLabels.emptyText}" 
    styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
    <af:column width="100px" align="center">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <af:outputText value="#{PageLabels.document}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <af:commandImageLink shortDesc="#{PageLabels.downloadDocument} ID: #{row.idDocument}" 
            icon="/skin/images/icons/pdf_icon4.gif">
            <af:setPropertyListener from="#{row.idDocument}" 
                to="#{DocListManagedBean.selectedIdDocument}" type="action"/>
            <af:fileDownloadActionListener contentType="application/pdf" 
                filename="#{row.documentName}" 
                method="#{DocListManagedBean.downloadFileListener}"/>
        </af:commandImageLink>
    </af:column>
    <af:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <af:outputText value="#{PageLabels.documentName}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <af:outputText value="#{row.documentName}"/>
    </af:column>
</af:table>
```

And it should now be so that (based on the document id) the file name should be computed, i.e. concatenated from several elements that are not in the object, the list of which is presented in *af:table*.
I already have the method returning the new file name in managed bean (called *generateDocumentFileName*). This method based on *selectedIdDocument* field in *DocListManagedBean* computes the correct filename and saves it in another field  *DocListManagedBean* named *selectedDocumentNewFilename*.

Is it possible (without changing - without adding another field to the type of object presented by af:table) before running the *af:downloadFileListener* method, to run another method in managed bean (my *generateDocumentFileName*) ? ... which would calculate the missing name, save it to the field *selectedDocumentNewFilename* in managed bean and then new filename will be available e.g. via

```
<af:fileDownloadActionListener contentType="application/pdf" 
                filename="#{DocListManagedBean.selectedDocumentNewFilename}" 
                method="#{DocListManagedBean.downloadFileListener}"/>
```

Where I should put a call to my *generateDocumentFileName* method in the code above or is it a stupid idea and I should have done it differently ?

Thanks for help,

koli

Answer (score 1):

The idea is mostly correct. You can programmatically set the file name in the filename attribute of the af:fileDownloadActionListener. (no need to call another function before hand - so you can remove the af:setPropertyListener).

You can get value from any iterator binding using the resolveExpression from the JsfUtils library. (detailled here https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-retreive-the-value-of-an-iterator-binding-variable-programmatically-in-adf/) For example your #{DocListManagedBean.selectedDocumentNewFilename} could look like this :

```java
private String selectedDocumentNewFilename;

public String getSelectedDocumentNewFilename(){      
  //Using below function you can easily get any of those value in your ADF Bean as follow : 
  Long currentIdDocument = (Long)resolveExpression("#{row.idDocument}");//if idDocument is a Long in your VO
  String currentNameDocument= (String)resolveExpression("#{row.documentName}"); //for example
  String anyOtherStringValueYouWant= (String)resolveExpression("#{bindings.YOUR_VO.YOUR_VO_ATTRIBUTE.inputValue}"); //for example
  //add any function to do something with this ID
  String generatedName = this.generateDocumentFileName(currentIdDocument);
  return "" + currentIdDocument.toString() + "_" + currentNameDocument + ".pdf"; //format as you like
  //or in your case : return "" + generatedName + ".pdf";
}


/**
 * Method for taking a reference to a JSF binding expression and returning
 * the matching object (or creating it).
 * @param expression EL expression
 * @return Managed object
 * @author : Duncan Mills, Steve Muench and Ric Smith's JSFUtils class
 */
public static Object resolveExpression(String expression) {
    FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
    Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);
    return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting to: 
- replace selectedDocumentNewFilename field in managed bean to method with the same name
- call this managed bean method from af:fileDownloadActionListener filename attribute
Am I right ?

Comment: I tried to do this with minor changes. I put the JSFUtils.resolveExpression function call directly into the generateDocumentFileName method. It now returns a filename and functionally corresponds to your  selectedDocumentNewFilename()
JSP code looks like this:
`<af:fileDownloadActionListener contentType="application/pdf" filename="#{DocListManagedBean.generateDocumentFileName}" method="#{DocListManagedBean.downloadFileListener}"/>`
But an error occurs.

Comment: Error message:
`Servlet failed with an Exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'my.project.view.managed.DocListManagedBean' does not have the property 'generateDocumentFileName'`

So is this possible to use in af:fileDownloadActionListener managed bean method name instead of class field name/properrty ?

Comment: Hi Koli, you can use any public String function in your bean but i was suggesting updating the existing "#{DocListManagedBean.selectedDocumentNewFilename}" function. Nldr: Update the selectedDocumentNewFilename public String function from your DocListManagedBean to get the info you want with resolveExpression and return the name as a String return value. (As described in this answer) This is because your goal is to programmaticaly set the filename attribute. :)

Comment: Hi @Cedric, so if I can use any function then this simple case should work correctly: My MB does not have field/property with name 'testFilename', I created only simple function/method. 
`public String testFilename(){
    return "filename.pdf";
}` 
and in JSP:
`<af:fileDownloadActionListener contentType="application/pdf" 
 filename="#{DocListManagedBean.testFilename}"
    method="#{DocListManagedBean.downloadFileListener}"/>`
and ... it still does not work

Comment: stacktrace fragment:`<Feb 9, 2021, 3:18:59,722 PM CET> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@213257813[app:myapp module:myapp path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an Exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'my.project.view.managed.DocListManagedBean' does not have the property 'testFilename'.
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:686)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:350)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)`
        ...

Comment: ... So if I try to use function/method in filename attribute instead of a field/property of MB then I have an error ..

BTW: Thank you for information about JSFUtils, it is very interesting and usable :-)

Comment: This errors mean your DocListManagedBean doesn't have the String testFilename + its accessor defined. If you really want to use another function than the existing specified selectedDocumentNewFilename (i don't understand why) then you need to add private String testFilename; at the start of your class and add its getter and setters. (Right click > Generate Accessor). You then need to add the logic to return your filename in the generated public String getTestFilename(){//HERE return "" + generatedName + ".pdf"} function. (But all this should be in another SO question)

Comment: Aaa, all right, I understand now. Your idea is to use some property of MB, or rather its getter, which is not really just a getter. Clever :-) . I'll try it out.

Comment: Of course - now it works.- Thank you for help.